# Check for css class on this.el inside of Backbone event object

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

```
events: {
    'click .pdf_preview' : 'onPreviewPdfClick',
    'click a.next' : '_nextPointer',
    'click a.prev' : '_prevPointer',
    'mouseleave .mediapop-item-container' : 'onMouseLeave',
    'mouseenter .mediapop-item-container' : 'onMouseEnter',
    // Editable events
    'click &.editable .dialog-header h3' : 'showEditTitleForm'  <--- this
},
```

I create a popup view that has an edit mode. While I could simply extend this view with an editable version, what I need is very basic, so instead I set it up so if you pass `this.options.editable` the `view.el` element will have an "editable" class on it.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to specify that selector inside of the event object. That way it won't event trigger if `this.options.editable` is not `true`. If Backbone supported a SASS style selector syntax then the above would work. The only alternative is to check for this.$el.hasClass('ediable') within `showEditTitleForm`.

I know if you set a selector like this:

```
'click' : 'myAction',
```

The click event will be applied to the `this.el` container. I'm looking to only apply the callback if the additional class is there.

Is it possible to do something similar to the above without adding a check within the callback method?

Edit: typo

Comment: Couldn't you put the `.editable` on the `<h3>` and use `'click .dialog-header h3.editable'` instead?

Comment: I could do that, but there will be a lot of other fields that I will make editable. This is only the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can always modify `events` before [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) is called, just be careful not to modify the `events` attached to the view's prototype. Something like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    if(this.options.editable) {
        this.events = _({}).extend(this.events, {
            'click .dialog-header h3': 'showEditTitleForm'
        });
    }
}
```

Note the `_({}).extend(...)`, that will merge `this.events` (which comes from the prototype) and the extra event into an empty object so that you don't accidentally alter the `events` in the prototype.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dNYXN/